# Non-generic Store method or non-generic GetTypedClient for ServiceStack Redis Client

Tags: redis, servicestack

I have an object, I don't know it's type in DesignTime. I have to persist it to Redis Db.

I need non-generic Store method or non-generic GetTypedClient(Type t) method.

There is internal _StoreAll method so I could not use.

Using As impossible because I don't know object's type in design-time

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [just added StoreObject](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/commit/e0f01bb303f73e4811a4971c2988f1ed1b50435d) to [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/) which lets you do this. This is available on v3.83 which is also [published to NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Redis/).

You could do this manually by just serializing the object to JSON and store it a key of your choosing using the RedisClient's [SetEntry](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisClient.cs#L50) method - Which also what happens behind the scenes when you use the Generic API.

Comment: I don't know the type of object so I could not use Store<T>.. SetEntry is not enough because I have to call RegisterTypeId to simulate Store method of RedisTypedClient<T>.

Comment: I've just added a StoreObject method that now supports this.